# Why aren't the elements of my Doubly Linked List displayed properly?

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers, doubly-linked-list

The following program receives input strings of the form `ins "name_to_insert" birthdate` and should insert this information in  a doubly linked list. The contents of the list are displayed after each insertion, along with the number of elements. The number of elements is being displayed correctly, but instead of the names and birth dates, *2686707* is being displayed n times (n=number of elements in the list).

I suspect something is wrong with my print function, *printList()*, but I couldn't figure out what.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "DLList.h"

typedef struct dataStructure
{
    int birthday;
    char *name;
} dataStructure;

int main()
{
    ListT *l=createList();
    char op[4], nameTemp[30], *name, s[50];
    int date;
    while (scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s)==1)
    {
        sscanf(s, "%s", op);
        if (strcmp(op, "ins")==0)
        {
            sscanf(s, "%*s %[^0-9]%d", nameTemp, &date);
            name=nameTemp+1; // Remove opening quotation mark
            name[strlen(name)-2]='\0'; // Remove closing quotation mark
                NodeT *p=createNode();
                p->data=(dataStructure*)malloc(sizeof(dataStructure));
                ((dataStructure*)p->data)->birthday=date;
                ((dataStructure*)p->data)->name=name;
                insertLastNode(l, p);
                printf("List length: %d\n", l->length);
                printList(l);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void printList(ListT *l)
{
    NodeT *p=l->first;
    while (p)
    {
        printf("%d %s\n", (((dataStructure*)p->data)->birthday, (dataStructure*)p->data)->name);
        p=p->next;
    }
    printf("--\n");
}
```

Contents of **DLList.h**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct nodetype
{
    struct nodetype *prev, *next;
    void *data;
} NodeT;

typedef struct
{
    int length;
    NodeT *first, *last;
} ListT;

NodeT *createNode();
ListT *createList();
void insertLastNode(ListT *l, NodeT *p);
```

Contents of **DLList.c**:

```
#include "DLList.h"

NodeT *createNode()
{
    NodeT *p=(NodeT*)malloc(sizeof(NodeT));
    p->next=p->prev=NULL;
    return p;
}

ListT *createList()
{
    ListT *l=(ListT*)malloc(sizeof(ListT));
    l->first=l->last=NULL;
    l->length=0;
    return l;
}

void insertLastNode(ListT *l, NodeT *p)
{
    if (l->first==NULL)
    {
        l->first=l->last=p;
        p->prev=p->next=NULL;
        l->length++;
    }
    else
    {
        p->prev=l->last;
        p->next=NULL;
        l->last->next=p;
        l->last=p;
        l->length++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't suppose you ran this in a **debugger**? Or maybe some liberally sprinkled `printf()` statements reporting states and/or values? The latter would demonstrate the problem as soon as you add a *second* node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two errors in the code.

**First:**
Instead of

```
((dataStructure*)p->data)->name=name;
```

do

```
((dataStructure*)p->data)->name = (char*)malloc(strlen(name)+1);
strcpy(((dataStructure*)p->data)->name, name);
```

to avoid memory leakage.

**Second**
In printList function there was a mistake with parentheses. Do as below:

```
printf("%d %s\n", ((dataStructure*)p->data)->birthday, ((dataStructure*)p->data)->name);
```

Everything else works. Here is output I got when tested the program.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! One more question: Why should I use `malloc(strlen(name)+1)` instead of `malloc(strlen(name))` ?

Comment: To reserve a byte for terminating zero. Also, remember to free(((dataStructure*)p->data)->name) when finished to work.

Answer (score 1):

In  your program, you are assigning the pointer to `name` as below:

```
((dataStructure*)p->data)->name=name;
```

This name is derived from the `sscanf` as below:

```
sscanf(s, "%*s %[^0-9]%d", nameTemp, &date);
name=nameTemp+1; // Remove opening quotation mark
name[strlen(name)-2]='\0'; // Remove closing quotation mark
```

This means that for every run of the loop, you are reading into the same `nameTemp` or `name` array and storing the same into the linked list. For every run of the loop, you may have to allocate a separate space for storing the `name` and assign the same to your node.

**EDIT 1:**

When you create a new node, there is also one type-casting issue. `p->data` is of `void *` type, in the code, I believe, the newly allocated memory is type-casted as `dataStructure *` as below

```
p->data=(dataStructure*)malloc(sizeof(dataStructure));
```

You could also change your data structure definition as below

```
typedef struct dataStructure
{
    int birthday;
    char name[64]; // Change from pointer to an array
} dataStructure;
```

And modify the logic in the loop to copy the name as below:

```
p->data=(dataStructure*)malloc(sizeof(dataStructure));
((dataStructure*)p->data)->birthday=date;
strcpy(((dataStructure*)p->data)->name, name); // Modified from pointer assignment to strcpy
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this in a debugger to see exactly what your function is doing.  For example if you're running from a Unix command line, compile with the `-g` flag, then run in `gdb`.  Set a breakpoint at the beginning of the function that is troubling you.  Google something like "gdb cheat sheet" for details, it's easy.